# rviz with pcl::PointCloud<T>

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to display a PCL point cloud of type pcl::PointCloud<T>, where T is a custom class, in rviz? Specifically, are there any requirements/limitations on the custom class T for it to play nice with rviz? It seems that the pcl_visualizer does provide a framework for displaying pcl::PointCloud<T> data through custom handlers. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12098/rviz-with-pcl::pointcloud%3Ct%3E/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have found an answer to my question. Please check the following link for details:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros

Section 4 "ROS C++ Interface" on the above web-page clearly mentions how it can be achieved. I still need to try it out and will update the answer once I can successfully visualize my pcl::PointCloud<T> data in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) with karma: 287 on 2011-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-09-09**:
unfortunately you never updated the answer ... :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just come across this question, while doing the same thing myself. So just in case anyone else finds this question I'll describe the solution.

If you need a point cloud to represent some custom point type beyond the standard options built into PCL (XYZ, XYZRGB, XYZI, etc) You have to define a custom PCL point type with the same behaviours as the built in types. Luckily there is a good tutorial showing you how to do this here:

[PCL Custom Point Type Tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php#how-to-add-a-new-pointt-type)

If you follow this fairly straightforward tutorial then create and publish a point cloud with this new type this it will be shown in RVIZ fine including a drop down of the addition variables which are now stored for your custom point type.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2